# POST passes null values only on my machine

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api

As far as I know, the configuration on my machine is the same as anyone else's on the team, and the following code is directly out of our source control unmodified, yet this behaves differently on my machine...

On my machine, this is what happens: RecalcModel is passed in as an object (i.e. RecalcModel is not null), but all of its properties are null.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("recalctotals")]
public HttpResponseMessage RecalculateTotals(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromBody] RecalcModel recalcModel)
{
    //...
}
```

If I modify the code like so, I get the correct result:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("recalctotals")]
public HttpResponseMessage RecalculateTotals(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromBody] object model)
{
    var recalcModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RecalcModel>(model.ToString());
    //...
}
```

My solution for this so far has been to set this up in a VM and run it there (where it runs as expected). It's not just this method, it's all of them.

Is there a configuration entry that I'm missing? IIS settings? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you compared the network request headers and body where it works against the request made on your computer?

Comment: I'm not quite sure where to look for headers, but I've checked in the Developer tools under Net for the headers and responses for that particular Javascript file... the only entry that looked different was that one used gzip and the other didn't.

Comment: The browsers' network tool is usually good for examining the request. Just be sure to examine `POST /recalctotals` rather than a possible redirect request.